# How to make the several devices execute MonkeyRunner (Jython scripts) at the same time?

Tags: jython, monkeyrunner

I have wrote a MonkeyRunner(Jython) script and I want running this script in several devices at the same time, please help me how to do it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()` to connect to devices use `device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(deviceId=DEVICE_ID)` where DEVICE_ID is the device id (as seen by adb) of the device that you are trying to connect to.